# How to port an Apple Dashboard widget to Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, widget, dashcode

I made visual aid type of widget (user needs to see through it) with Dashcode, now I want to port it to Windows XP & 7.

I heard that StarDock DesktopX Pro can export standalone widgets as .exe but I don't know if those are native Windows widgets.

Is there a Dashcode equivalent for Windows? (I happen not to know JavaScript !)

Answer (score 1):

There is no Dashcode equivalent for Windows, the Windows "widgets" that exist currently are just packages of HTML/JS/CSS and as far as I have seen do not have a widespread adoption rate.

If you are looking to do something like an overlay then a "widget" in the Windows environment is probably not the correct route. You would be better off writing a native application.

Comment: Why would Mac OS X users adopt it and not Windows users ?? A simple google search returns tons of websites for sidebar gadgets and people share zip of hundreds of gadgets. Anyway, why for an overlay I should choose a native application ? BTW does Windows 7 uses offers the same sidebar gadget feature as Vista did ?

Comment: Yes you will find many gadgets as they are called in Windows, but the market is niche and not general adoption (from what I have seen, this may not be true but I believe it to be true.) The feature is effectively hidden on Windows under a configuration menu, there isn't a dashboard like on OSX. In Vista there was the concept of the sidebar but Windows7 has removed the need for the gadgets to be encapsulated in the sidebar and can now be freely placed on the desktop. I have seen gadgets similar to the one described but they work inconsistently at best and that is why I suggested a native app.

Comment: BTW what's the market share of each solution on Windows ? MS, Yahoo!, Google, Stardock, Opera etc @Quintin Robinson

Answer (score 0):

An exported .exe from DesktopX is not a native Windows gadget. It's either a self contained application, or it require DesktopX client to be installed. ( Depending of which variant you export. )

You can however export a .gadget which will act as a Windows gadget. Here's a quick tutorial article: http://www.wincustomize.com/article/155475